# How to get child element with parent element with the help of "driver. findElement().findElement()'?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Here you can see the `xpath1` and `xpath2` are partially same. I don't want to use two separate `xpath`s for two related scenario. I have to use only `xpath1`.

```
String xpath1="//div[@id='name']";  //parent element
String xpath2="div[@id='name']/div[5]"; //child element
WebElement ele1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath1"));
WebElement ele2=driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath1")).finElement(By.xpath());
```

I want to get `ele2` with the help of `xpath1` only.

Please suggest me how to do and how can I give the enter 5 in `Div[5]`dynamically.

And what is the concept of `driver.findElement().findElement();`?

Comment: What do you mean by "enter 5 in Div[5] dynamically? Do you know that index off hand by other means?

Comment: means i have to send the index value after getting from other element.

Answer (score 0):

To use an element as a parent what you would want to do is something like the following:

```
WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath1")); //parent element
WebElement ele2 = ele1.findElement(By.xpath("./div[5]")); // child - note "./" very important
```

Not entirely sure what you mean by making "div[5]" but what I have done before is grab all elements then iterate through them to get the right index. For instance:

```
int  i = 0;
List<WebElement> elements  = driver.findElements(By.Xpath("xpath"));
for (i; i < elements.size(); ++i) {
    if (elements.text().equals("blah") 
         break;
}

WebElement el2 = el1.findElement(By.Xpath("./div[" + i + "]")); 
...
...
```

In any case, using that notation is generally not recommended because it can easily change. Ideally you'd want to use a more robust xpath or css selector in the absence of an id.

Answer (score 0):

> Please suggest me how to do and how can I give the enter 5 in Div[5]dynamically.

This way? I don't get it at all.

```
String xpath1 = "//div[@id='name']";  //parent element
String xpath2 = "/div[5]"; //child element
WebElement ele2=driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath1)).finElement(By.xpath(xpath2));
```

> And what is the concept of driver.findElement().findElement();?

After the first element, you can use your `WebElement` as an HTML/XML root page, and can still querying it to find more elements. It is useful if you need to query a node and they subnodes more than two or three times, without repeat the base node path query.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.Id("name")); //for your parent element
WebElement ele2 = ele1.findElement(By.xpath("./div[5]")); // your child element
```

or

```
WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath1")); //for your parent element
WebElement ele2 = ele1.findElement(By.xpath("./div[position()=5]")); // your child element
```

or

```
WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath1")); //for your parent element
WebElement ele2 = ele1.findElement(By.xpath("./child::div[5]")); // your child element
```

or use child first and then go to parent

```
WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath2")); //for child element
WebElement ele2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath2 + "/parent::*")); // your parent element
```

if you look for some xpath examples you there is a nice [cheatsheet here](http://ricostacruz.com/cheatsheets/xpath).

Answer (score 0):

Simply locate the Parent element and then Child element.

```
//parent element locator
WebElement ParentElement = driver.findElement("your locator")); 

//Child element locator
WebElement ChildElement = ParentElement.findElement("your locator"));
```

Instead of using this

```
String xpath1="//div[@id='name']";  //parent element
String xpath2="//div[@id='name']/div[5]"; //child element
WebElement ele1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath1"));
WebElement ele2=driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath1")).finElement(By.xpath());
```

Use this:

```
String xpath1="//div[@id='name']";  //parent element
String xpath2="./div[5]"; //child element
WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath1));
WebElement ele2 = ele1.findElement(By.xpath(xpath2));
```